# How to manage custom table product qty for different seller for same product?

Tags: magento-1.9, quantity, out-of-stock, multi-vendor

I am making seller price comparison marketplace module.If  `seller1` create `P1` product `P1` product will display in catalog product grid and if `seller2` want to sell `P1` product so `seller2` details will stored in custom table like `product_id,seller_id,qty` will enter in my custom table so My question is If P1 product is out of stock cart page for `seller1` so magento showing error message about out of stock quantity in cart page and in onepage checkout page redirect checkout page and hide proceed to checkout button in cart page this point `seller2` 's `P1` product can not `proceed to checkout` and how to manage custom table product qty manage in magento ? I just need hint or flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although i did not test it and it is also pretty outdated, you might wanna try the following open source module:

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/MultiStock

there are also other extensions available, just search for magento multi stock.

If none of the extensions fit your needs, the hackathon extension might give you a few hints on how you can solve your problem